# To be V-ed vs to v-ed

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, verb-agreement

I don't understand why I can't use "to be locked up" instead of "to locked up" mentioned in this right sentence "I've often wondered what it would be like to locked up in a house for twelve weeks with ten strangers."

Comment: You can lock yourself up (active), or you can be locked up (passive).

Comment: "I've often wondered what it would be like to locked up in a house for twelve weeks with ten strangers" is wrong.

Comment: You can use it; _be_ has obviously been left out of the sentence.

Comment: You can discard *both* or *neither* of the highlighted words in *I've often wondered what it would be like [**to be**] locked up in a house...,* but you can't just discard ***one*** of them.

Answer (score 2):

"to be locked up" The is the simple past passive form:

"He **was locked up** by the police."

"to lock**ed** up" - this is wrong = lock**ed** is the past participle.

"To lock up" this is the active form of the verb, "The police locked him up."

Compare

He **was locked up** by the police.

with

"The police locked him up."